# Версия приложения в GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play

Такой вопрос, каждый раз при добавлении apk в `Google Play`, нужно увеличивать версию приложения. Когда заливаешь apk, что проверяет `Google Play` `versionCode` ?
 или  `versionName` ? Могут ли `versionCode` и `versionName` отличаться? Например `versionCode 5`, а `versionName "1.1.5"` ? Можно ли заливать приложение с разными `versionCode`, но одинаковыми `versionName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Когда заливаешь apk, что проверяет Google Play versionCode ? или versionName ?

`versionCode`

> Могут ли versionCode и versionName отличаться?

да, `versionName` - человеко-читаемая версия, например `1.1.15`
 `versionCode` - *номер* версии, например `15`

> Можно ли заливать приложение с разными versionCode, но одинаковыми
>   versionName?

Да, можно